# What's the equivalent of php time() in mssql?

Tags: php, sql-server

For example if I execute the code below under my Windows 7-I have PHP running under windows 7/IIS.

```
echo time() I will get this 1304972050
```

How can I get the same result in MSSQL?

Comment: You want the unix timestamp or the date format applicable for a MS SQL Date column?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(ss, '1/1/1970 05:00:00', GETUTCDATE())
```

Should do.

UPDATED per comment.

Comment: You can't use GetDate() if your server isn't in EST time.

Comment: because the epoch is 1/1/1970 00:00:00 EST and if your server is in the UK you'd need to subract 5 hours.  since getdate gives you the server time.

Answer (score 4):

To get the epoch time in sql:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(s,'19700101 05:00:00:000',GETUTCDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't get this out of the box, but you can find functions defined on sql server forums, eg. http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=66858.