# compare timestamp to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a timestamp column in db which is generated by php and stored as varchar(max).

```
id   sched_timestamp   data
--   ---------------   ----
1    1436882400        foo
2    1438092000        bar
3    1438005600        xxx
...
```

What i want to do is to get all the rows in the past(timestamp earlier than `current_timestamp`).

The problem is it seems like sql server does not have a native way of getting current timestamp, it gives me a formatted date looks like `2015-07-28 14:19:36.893`.

I want to do this in sql not in php as this table has more than 100k rows of data and i only need ~10 of them.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The timestamp type does not represent a time of day.

Comment: @shawnt00 it is not in timestamp type, it is in varchar. That timestamp is from php function `time();` and then stored to db

Comment: We know its a timestamp.but still you cant compare as its nto a time of day..you need a day component as well.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942002/whats-the-equivalent-of-php-time-in-mssql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing this query should fix it

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(str,'19700101 05:00:00:000',GETUTCDATE())
```